# Strange error of vertical output on mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, galera

Mysql 8 on Debian, with Galera 4.

```
mysql> select capabilities,view_seqno  from wsrep_cluster;
+--------------+------------+
| capabilities | view_seqno |
+--------------+------------+
|       184703 |        277 |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Works fine, but when I want the vertical output...

```
mysql> select capabilities,view_seqno  from wsrep_cluster \G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
capabilities: 184703
  view_seqno: 277
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql>
```

Why the error "no query specified" appear?

Comment: Because of the `;` at the end....   Try a `;` on a blank line and you also get "No query specified"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select capabilities,view_seqno  from wsrep_cluster \G;
```

You have executed two queries. The first ends with the `\G`. The second ends with the semicolon. The contents of the second query are the empty string.

Comment: Perfect, so after \G no ; is needed.

Comment: Right, only one statement terminator is needed. The manual says: [type an SQL statement, end it with ;, \g, or \G and press Enter.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html)